# NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I have constructed a messaging application, but it seems to have incorrect syntax:

```
 from tkinter import messagebox


from AESEncDec import *
from MD5Hashing import *
from RSAEncDec import *

color = 'lightblue' #color our background


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400

        # Set configuration our frame
        self.config(width = self.frame_width, height = self.frame_height, bg = color) 
        self.pack()

        # Create textBox for input data
        self.textbox_one = Text()
        self.textbox_one.place(x = 30, y = 170, height = 200, width = 300 )

        # Create textBox for result
        self.textbox_two = Text()
        self.textbox_two.place(x = 370, y = 170, height = 200, width = 300 )

        label_input_text = Label( text = "Input text: ", bg = color)
        label_input_text.place(x = 30, y = 155, height = 10, width = 70 )
```

During execution I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/artur/Documents/MScProject/MSc Project/Task #179276/main_program.py", line 11, in 
>           class Application(Frame):
>       NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Frame`](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/frame.html) is a class from the `tkinter` module.

To fix:

```
from tkinter import Frame
```

See an example in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program

You also need to import `Text` and `Label`:

```
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label
```

Or:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Here is how you can fix your code (I removed the unused imports):

```
import tkinter

color = 'lightblue'  # color our background


class Application(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        super(Application, self).__init__(root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400

        # Set configuration our frame
        self.config(width=self.frame_width, height=self.frame_height, bg=color)
        self.pack()

        # Create textBox for input data
        self.textbox_one = tkinter.Text()
        self.textbox_one.place(x=30, y=170, height=200, width=300)

        # Create textBox for result
        self.textbox_two = tkinter.Text()
        self.textbox_two.place(x=370, y=170, height=200, width=300)

        label_input_text = tkinter.Label(text="Input text: ", bg=color)
        label_input_text.place(x=30, y=155, height=10, width=70)


root = tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```