# NameError: name 'tk' is not defined in the object class

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I have constructed an application, the source starts like this:

```
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label    

from AESEncDec import *
from MD5Hashing import *
from RSAEncDec import *

color = 'lightblue' #color our background

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400
```

But last piece of it cannot execute:

```
#create object TK class
the_window = Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
#create object Application
app = Application(the_window)
#run our Application
app.mainloop()
```

And it gives the NameError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/artur/Documents/MScProject/MSc Project/Task #179276/main_program.py", line 169, in 
>       the_window = Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
>   NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

How should I define it properly in this case?

Comment: Do you need to import Tk?

Comment: You do realise this is exactly the same problem as with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252200/nameerror-name-frame-is-not-defined-python) just with a different name you forgot to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss an import statement : `from tkinter import Tk`

The best way to avoid conflict, is to import the whole module, eventually with an alias to make it short (but don't forget to add `tk.` everywhere you've called a tkinter widget):

```
import tkinter as tk

from AESEncDec import *
from MD5Hashing import *
from RSAEncDec import *

color = 'lightblue' #color our background

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400


#create object TK class
the_window = tk.Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
#create object Application
app = Application(the_window)
#run our Application
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It gives a new typo of error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Documents/MScProject/MSc Project/Task #179276/main_program.py", line 170, in <module>
    the_window = Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Whats wrong with typing?

Comment: notice the lowercase used in `import tkinter as tk` and then you need `tk.Tk(className = " Cryptographic")`. `Tk` is the main class, `tk` is the module,  sorry for the confusing alias, it is pretty common

Comment: Well I have changed the beginning to import tkinter as Tk and the last piece to:
 #create object TK class
the_window = tk.Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
#create object Application
app = Application(the_window)
#run our Application
app.mainloop()

I still get the same error :(

Comment: better use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `import tkinter as Tk`